# Add intentional latency in express

Tags: node.js, express

Im using express with node.js, and testing certain routes. I'm doing this tute at http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Im calling the `http://localhost:3000/wines` via ajax (the content doesn't matter). But I want to test latency. Can I do something like make express respond after 2 seconds? (I want to simulate the ajax loader and I'm running on localhost so my latency is pretty much nil)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just call `res.send` inside of a [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_settimeout_cb_ms):

```
setTimeout((() => {
  res.send(items)
}), 2000)
```

Answer (score 110):

Use as middleware, for all your requests

```
  app.use(function(req,res,next){setTimeout(next,1000)});
```

Comment: used it, thx, as es6:  `app.use((req, res, next) => setTimout(next, 1000))`

Comment: @ya_dimon, there is misspelled setTimout, it should be setTimeout

Comment: the order was important for me. Set the delay middleware before you setup the `static` files middleware (in my case I wanted to delay such static assets)

Comment: It is so simple. I can't understand why I didn't think of that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

To apply it globaly on all requests you can use the following code:

```
app.use( ( req, res, next ) => {
    setTimeout(next, Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 2000 ) + 100 ) );
});
```

---

**Time values are:**

Max = 2000 (sort of.... min value is added so in reality its 2100)

Min = 100

Comment: With Lodash: `app.use((req, res, next) => setTimeout(next, random(100, 2000)))`

Comment: A 70kb library just for a random function?

Comment: One could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.random. Also with ES6 modules cherry pick only the needed dependency can be imported. I use Lodash everywhere.

Comment: Or just maybe .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

Try [connect-pause](https://github.com/flesler/connect-pause) module. It adds delay to all or only some routes in your app.

Comment: Simple module that effectively does what @maggocnx 's solution advises.

Comment: Call me old school, but adding a dependency for 1 line of code seems overkill: https://github.com/flesler/connect-pause/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 6):

```
app.get('/fakeDelay', function(req,res){
    let ms = req.query.t;
    ms = (ms>5000 || isNaN(ms)) ? 1000 : parseInt(ms); 
    setTimeout((()=> res.status(200).send({delay:ms})), ms);
})
```

Then request the URL as: http://localhost/fakeDelay/?t=2000
*(max 5000ms and default of 1000ms on this example)*

**Update:**
Using a Promise. The function 'sleep' can be used for delaying any Express response or other async function.

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

app.get('/fakeDelay', async (req, res) => {
  await sleep(500);
  res.send([])
})
```

Answer (score 3):

just add a comment on top of the solution of @maggocnx : put this middleware early (before your route handler)

`app.use(function(req,res,next){setTimeout(next,1000)});`

Answer (score 1):

You could also just write your own generic delay handler using a Promise or callback (using a [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) promise in this case):

**pause.js:**

```
var q = require('q');

function pause(time) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    // if the supplied time value is not a number, 
    // set it to 0, 
    // else use supplied value
    time = isNaN(time) ? 0 : time;

    // Logging that this function has been called, 
    // just in case you forgot about a pause() you added somewhere, 
    // and you think your code is just running super-slow :)
    console.log('pause()-ing for ' + time + ' milliseconds');

    setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, time);

    return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports = pause;
```

then use it however you'd like:

**server.js:**

```
var pause = require('./pause');

router.get('/items', function (req, res) {
    var items = [];

    pause(2000)
        .then(function () {
            res.send(items)
        });

});
```

Comment: How it is better than generic `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [express-delay](https://npm.io/package/express-delay) package.

The code below will delay all incoming requests by one second.

```
const app = require('express')();
const delay = require('express-delay');
app.use(delay(1000));
```

The package also offers the possibility to introduce a random delay within specified boundaries, e.g. by calling `delay(1000, 2000)` for a delay between one and two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted a way to have the same processing time for all of my endpoints.

The solution I found is to override one of the Response methods :

```js
/* MINIMUM DELAY */
const minDelay = 200; /* ms */
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const tmp = res.json;
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    (res.json as any) = async (body: any) => {
        await new Promise((re) => setTimeout(re, minDelay - new Date().getTime() + start));
        tmp.apply(res, [body]);
    };
    next();
});
```

This way an attacker would not be able to differentiate failed login requests from OK requests just by looking at the response time :)