# Add intentional latency in db.collection.save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Which is the best way to intentionally add latency to db.collection.save() for unit testing purposes.

Let say, I have function that I need to test:

```
function() {
  let item = collection.findOne({});
  ...
  collection.save(item);
}
```

I would like collection.save to be delayed without changing the function code.

Basically I'm looking for something like this [express pause middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954962/2215679) but for MongoDB driver.

Comment: But the function `findOne` is asynchronous...

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447407/whats-the-equivalent-of-javas-thread-sleep-in-javascript

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Comment: Thank you @dnickless but none of these solutions works for me, I mean, as I mentioned in the question, I need to simulate the delay on collection.save without changing the main function that calls it (for unit testing purposes)

Comment: I just added into description the similar library that I'm looking for @dnickless