# Math random numbers between 50 and 80

Tags: javascript

I know there's several questions on this, but I'm struggling to find out how to use Math.random to get random numbers between two high integers?

So, for example, between 50 and 80. I thought this would work...

```
'left': Math.floor((Math.random() * 80) + 50) + '%'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random value between two numbers in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe `* 30` instead of `* 80` ?

Comment: Generate a number between 0 and 30 then add 50 to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to know the range of the random.

Between 50 and 80, the range is 30 (80 - 50 = 30), then you add 1.

Therefor, the random would look like this :

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 50
```

Comment: This will actually never give a result of 80. Check out Kayz1's solution.

Answer (score 34):

Assuming the range is inclusive on both ends:

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here consider your min=50 and max = 80  refer below code:

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

This will solve your problem. You can try any range by changing min and max.