# Button onclick increase 1-10 randomly

Tags: javascript, button

So, say I have a number, *c*, and when I click a button it randomly increases by another number, *b*, which is any number between 1-10.  I have tried math.floor(math.random()) and document-getElementById('#id').innerhtml="".  Please help, preferably save *c* as a variable.  Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code that you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random value between two numbers in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: I've suggested you an implementation for that random number generator functionality, but update your answer with more code so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10)
```

Math.random() generates a random number between 0 and 1 (except) [0,1[.
Here further info about Math.random(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

```
var c = 120;

window.addEventListener("load",function(){

   document.getElementById('btnRandom').addEventListener("click",function(){

        //this code goes inside click event function
        var b = c + Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML= "random: " + b;

   }, false);

}, false);


<div id="results"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnRandom" value="Random"/>
```

And a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRSZj/

Regards.

Comment: `math` is undefined. `Math` is what you need ;)

Comment: You may want to be a bit more specific about what `Math.random()` does. Your current statement implies that `11` is a possible result.

Comment: True! I've heard that a lot here at SO, never had any trouble with their content dough.. I mainly use it to check things about CSS properties, and JavaScript Native... but that's not my only source :) , with so many sources of info, most of the times I complete the lack of info with knowledge from books.

Comment: I always start my JS doc lookups with "MDN" :3

Comment: Nice... Guess I've been living under a rock... Nice source will follow your advice for sure!

Comment: Okay, I already know how to use Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

Comment: But I need to know how to have you click a button, and it adds between 1-10 to the total _c_.  preferable that total is a variable...and I should be able to use document.getElementById('#id').innerhtml=""; to show "You have _c_ objects"

Comment: hmmm, you put: var b = candy **+** ....   :(  you should have put a **+=** instead of a **+**