# How to load random html page into div from folder

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for the right way to load a random html page (from a folder, which contains all the pages) into a div.
This is what I've done for now:

```
<html>  
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#CONTENTS").load("contenuti/1.html"); 
}); 
</script>

</head>  
<body>

<div id="CONTENTS"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the right way is to transform the "1.html" in "*.html" and then insert a random code.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(function() {
   var max = 10, min = 1;
   $("#CONTENTS").load("contenuti/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)+".html"); 
});
```

The above will take random html pages named from 1 to 10.

The random number code courtesy: Francisc's answer to the question [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: fwiw `var max = 10, min = 1;Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min` may return `8.37721847370267` . `Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)` to return `8` ?