# populate an array with random values with javascript using given parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to populate with an array with a given number of elements(this parameter is stated in the function) given that there is a startValue and endValue for example populate myArray with 5 numbers 
between 5 and 15.

```
function populateArray(num, startValue, endValue){
var j,
    localArray=[];
for(j=startValue;j<=endValue;j+=1){
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random()* j);
    localArray.push(k);
}
console.log(localArray);
}
```

where num is the number of elements wanted in the array _ I don't know how to implement this. thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) generate a random number between 5 and 15; 2) push this into an array; 3) repeat 1) and 2) 4 more times.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vwpqaLpy/)**</kbd>

```
function populateArray(num, startValue, endValue){
    var j,
        localArray=[];
    for(j=0; j <= num; j++){
        var k = randomIntFromInterval(startValue, endValue);
        localArray.push(k);
    }
    return localArray; 
}

//From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7228322/402706
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

console.log(populateArray(10, 8, 12));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=0;j<=num;j+=1){
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random()* (endValue-startValue) + startValue);
    localArray.push(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it the wrong way:

Your for loop should be the amount of number that you are required, thus something like this in pseudo code.

> For j while j < num increase by 1

Then to get the random number, you are also having it wrong. `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. Which means that you can do something like this:

space between the 2 numbers is `Math.abs(endValue - startValue)`. The absolute isn't necessary but just in case you mix the numbers. Then you'll have to do something like this:

> Multiply the random value by the space and add the startValue as an offset. Then you can use floor to remove the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
function createRandomArray(length, minValue, maxValue) {
  // assert(minValue <= maxValue)
  // assert(length >= 0)

  var arr = [];
  var multiplier = maxValue - minValue + 1;

  while (length--) {
    arr.push(minValue + Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier));
  }

  return arr;
}

// and that's how it can be used in your case:
var randArr = createRandomArray(5, 5, 15);
```

In your solution, you somehow ended up using range start and end numbers to define the size of resulting array (in `for` loop).

Two sidenotes here. First, when you need to execute the loop strictly N times, `for` loop can be replaced with `while (n--)` one. I often use the latter to differentiate these `N-times` cases.

Second, when dealing with ranges, there's often a confusion about inclusiveness of their `end` (and sometimes `start`) values. `min` and `max` name prefixes are far more clear in this aspect.