# Changing interval time to random?

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a way to change the way my javascript number counter is working. Now it just counts up every second but I want it to count at random times between 1 second and 15 seconds.

```
function startCount(){
    timer = setInterval (count, 1000);  
}

function count(){
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(removeCommas(el.innerHTML));
    el.innerHTML = addCommas(currentNumber+1);
}

function addCommas(nStr){
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }

    return x1 + x2 + '.00';
}

function removeCommas(aNum){
    //remove any commas
    aNum=aNum.replace(/,/g,"");

    //remove any spaces
    aNum=aNum.replace(/\s/g,"");

    return aNum;
}
```

Can someone help me change the count time to random numbers?

Comment: Do you want a random but fixed interval, or should every new timeout have a random duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the interval is between 1 and 15 seconds and changed after each interval. `setIntervsal()` does not fit. `setTimeout()` is here a good choice, because of the single interval of waiting. Every next interval gets a new time to wait and has to be called again. The random waiting time is archieved through `Math.random()`, a function whicht returns floating points numbers between 0 and 1. With a factor and forced to integer and a padding of 1000 milli second we get the wanted interval.

(A word to former solution: first, i thought just a fixed random interval will suit, but the question ariesed, what kind of interval is requested.)

```
function startCount() {
    setTimeout(count, 1000 + Math.random() * 14000 | 0);
}
function count() {
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(removeCommas(el.innerHTML));
    el.innerHTML = addCommas(currentNumber + 1);
    startCount();
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP (and any other reader) appreciates an explanation of the changes you made.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how to change the el.innerHTML = addCommas(currentNumber + 1); to a random number - like between 250 and 1500?

Comment: `250 + Math.random() * 1250 | 0` a fixed part of 250 and a random value of 0 ... 1250 forced to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`(Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1)*1000`

instead of the fixed 1000ms

[Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: If you think this is the answer, then you should vote to close the question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` in `startCount()` with a random time parameter, and call it at the end of `count` function.

```
function startCount()
{   
    timer = setTimeout (count, Math.floor(Math.random() * 14000) + 1000);  
}


function count()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(removeCommas(el.innerHTML));
    el.innerHTML = addCommas(currentNumber+1);
    startCount()
}
```