# Random number between 0.3 and 1 using jquery

Tags: jquery

How tocreate a random number between 0.3 and 1.

I know that `Math.random()` creates a number between 0 and 1.

However im using css scale and below 0.3 is to small.

Comment: JQuery does not have any native support for random... So you really can't.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov jQuery does not *need* "native support for random", because `Math.random` works just fine. ;-)

Comment: Yeah dont mark him down for asking an honest question. Probability new jquery.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @zwol OP clearly knows how to get random number with JavaScript. There is possiblye something special about need to use JQuery, otherwise it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript (which it apparently is based on OP's comment to strict JavaScript answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an equal chance of any number over the range 0.3 to 1, then

```
Math.random() * 0.7 + 0.3
```

Multiplying a number from 0 to 1 by 0.7 will give you a number from 0 to 0.7, and the + 0.3 will then get you to the range 0.3 to 1.0.

Comment: @MattHammond if this is the correct answer, then you should modify your question and remove the jQuery part.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get between 0.3 and 1, you would put:

```
var min = 0.3,
    max = 1,
    var answer = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(4);
    alert(answer);
```

0.3 is an our start number1 is a number of possible results
Or

```
(Math.random() * (1 - 0.3) + 0.3).toFixed(4)
```

toFixed is used to convert a number into a string,

Comment: The `1` in the first example and the `(0.1 - 0.3)` in the second should both be `0.7`.

Comment: @zwol No it should be 1 not 0.7

Comment: @AndrewKralovec The code you originally had would have generated numbers in the range (0.3, 1.3).  You do appear to have fixed it.