# Select random element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple div elements with same class dot under parent div like this

```
<div id="dots">
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   ...
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
</div>
```

How can I using JavaScript select all elements with `class="dot"` and on every 5 seconds apply certain class on random element.

```
randomElement.addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: I think better select by `getElementByClass`

Comment: What­ have you tried?

Comment: Clarify: and remove class from previous dot or just add to new with preserving previous?

Comment: I bet no one has ever tried selecting a random element before. Very good question. A+ unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is basically first select all dots, then on each periodic activation run remove previously set class and set it again to random element with index [within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript) from 0 to dots `count - 1`.

Here is an example.

```js
var $dots = $('#dots .dot');

function activate() {
    $dots.removeClass('active')
         .eq([Math.floor(Math.random()*$dots.length)])
         .addClass('active');
 setTimeout(activate, 1000);
}

activate();
```

```css
#dots .dot {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
#dots .dot.active {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dots">
   <div class="dot"></div>
   <div class="dot"></div>
   <div class="dot"></div>
   <div class="dot"></div>
   <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
function addClassToRandomDotElement(){
    var dotElements = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    var totalDotElements = dotElements.length;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalDotElements ) + 1;
    var randomDotElement = dotElements[randomNumber];
    randomDotElement.addClass('someClass');
}

setInterval(function(){
    addClassToRandomDotElement();
},5000);
```

Comment: Should be `Math.floor(Math.random() * totalDotElements);` or the first element will never be selected, and there's a chance of going out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Still one more different way, easy to understand.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/81ap3w6h/2/)

```js
var noofdot = $(".dot").length;
setInterval(function () {
    $(".dot").removeClass("someClass");
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * noofdot) + 1);
    $(".dot:nth-child(" + x + ")").addClass("someClass");
}, 5000);
```

```css
.someClass
{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dots">
    <div class="dot">.</div>
    <div class="dot">.</div>
    <div class="dot">.</div>...
    <div class="dot">.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iteration over all elements:

1. iteration over all elements
2. Add class to random elements
3. Remove that elements from the iteration list.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");


setInterval(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
  elements[random].className += " extra";
  delete elements[random];
}, 1000);
//change 1000 to 5000. This is the interval speed in milisec.
```

```css
.extra {
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dot">Test</div>
  <div class="dot">Test</div>
  <div class="dot">Test</div>
  <div class="dot">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way:

```js
function changeColor(){
  var randInt = getRandomInt(0, $(".dot:not(.newStyle)").length -1);
  $($(".dot:not(.newStyle)")[randInt]).addClass('newStyle');
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


setInterval(function(){
    changeColor();
},3000);
```

```css
.newStyle{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot">testing</div>
<div class="dot">test</div>
<div class="dot">cool</div>
<div class="dot">more</div>
<div class="dot">cat</div>
<div class="dot">lol</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below should work for you.

```js
window.radomNo = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    if(radomNo) $(".dot:eq("+ radomNo +")").toggleClass("randomcss");
    window.radomNo = Math.floor((Math.random() * $(".dot").length) + 1);
 $(".dot:eq("+ radomNo +")").toggleClass("randomcss");
},1000);
```

```css
.randomcss {
    background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dots">
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
     <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
     <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
     <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
   <div class="dot"> . </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/7qgvru5p/

Answer (score -1):

if you use jquery you can try the following:

```
randomElements = jQuery("div").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,5)
```

Comment: downvoted since you do not set an interval, or add a class to the randomelements