# How to add random test case in codewars?

Tags: javascript, random, testcase

I have function in codewars.com `getNumberLength(n)` which gets some number in different digits and should give you the length of number. For exampl number `n=2000` shoul give 4.
I also added some test cases with `Test.assertEquals()` method, but now I need to add test case with random numbers, does somebody know how to do that in codewars, because in their documentation I could not find explanation for random test case. They have their own test case methods, guys who have experience help please? For information function written in javascript.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Generate random numbers, and add a embedded sample solution in the test file, to run test user's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a function to generate random numbers like what is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript). Then you can doing something like:

```
function random(min,max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
};

Test.assertEquals(getNumberLength(random(1, 100)), 3)
Test.assertEquals(getNumberLength(random(1, 1000)), 4)
Test.assertEquals(getNumberLength(random(1, 10000)), 5)
Test.assertEquals(getNumberLength(random(1, 100000)), 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

The test for my Kata with random Numbers look like this:

```
Test.describe("Random Tests:", function() {
  function solution(d) {
    if (d<3) return d*40;
    return (d<7) ? d*40-20 : d*40-50;  
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let days = ~~(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    Test.assertEquals(rentalCarCost(days), solution(days));
  }
});
```

I hope this is a good example and helps you.