# Click handler is called multiple times in jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting familiar with jQuery and making a little application where a red box moves around the screen and the user has to try and click on it and when the user does an `alert()` box pops up but the problem is that the `alert()` keeps popping up even after 'ok' is pressed. The only way I can stop it is to repeatedly click 'ok' and eventually it goes away.

Here is the code that displays the alert box:

```
function Animate() {
    var _newPosition = GetNewPosition();
    // Sets new position of div
    div.animate({
        top: _newPosition[0],
        left: _newPosition[1]
    }, function () {
        div.on('click', function () {
            alert('You clicked the box!');
        });
        Animate();
    });
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etws79q6/) that reproduces the problem

I originally thought that I could solve it by returning `false` after the call to the `alert()` for example:

```
div.on('click', function () {
    alert('You clicked the box!');
    return false;
});
```

But that didn't work either.

I know this should be a simple thing to figure out but I cant quite seem to get my thumb on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click handler is recursively called in the animation complete callback which is binding the `click` event on the element multiple times. So, when the element is clicked the handler is being called multiple times.

To solve the issue, bind the event only once.

```
function Animate() {
    var _newPosition = GetNewPosition();
    // Sets new position of div
    div.animate({
        top: _newPosition[0],
        left: _newPosition[1]
    }, Animate);
}
```

And in [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Animate();

    div.on('click', function() {
        // Code here
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

---

Using `Animate` as reference to the animation complete callback is same as

```
function() {
    Animate();
}
```

The function reference will be passed to the `animate` and it'll be called when the animation is completed.

---

**Suggestions:**

1. Use `mousedown` event to track the click on moving object
2. Use random duration for `animate`.

[**FIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/oc2ax5wb/)

```js
var div = $('#box');
$(document).ready(function() {
  Animate();

  div.on('mousedown', function() {
    // Code here
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});

function GetNewPosition() {
  // Get dimentions of the window and remove the div area
  var h = $(window).height() - 50;
  var w = $(window).width() - 50;
  // New height and width is auto generated
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
  return [nh, nw];
}

function Animate() {
  var _newPosition = GetNewPosition();
  // Sets new position of div
  div.animate({
    top: _newPosition[0],
    left: _newPosition[1]
  }, (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1), Animate);
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="success"></h3>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but what does Animate do instead of Animate()?

Comment: I'd also suggest to use `mousedown`, a `click` is almost impossible on faster movements making the *game* unfair. Also to decrease the speed: `}, 5000, Animate);` or even [a random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-value-between-two-numbers-in-javascript) instead of 5000.

Comment: @DecompileCodex `Animate` is a callback reference, `Animate()` is an immediate execution.

Comment: Right thanks, I thought that $(document).ready(function(){...code...}) was only called once when the page was loaded and thats it

Comment: @DecompileCodex and it is. But in your code, every time Animate ends (triggers again the callback Animate) > inside your re-called function you're again asserting another click event to the same element.

Comment: Ohk thanks, so is the callback (animate) like a delegate?

Comment: I get it, every time the box is clicked, the page is reloaded hence why document.ready is loaded every time. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @DecompileCodex The `ready` will be called only once when page is loaded and adding the code to bind click event in it means binding the event only once

Answer (score 1):

Event is getting bound multiple times as it is in animate function. Instead binding click event in animate bind it in `$(document).ready(function () {});` so that it will only get bound once.

Please find updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surajAhirrao/etws79q6/1/)