# Why does my Button with a script not work sometimes?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've made a simple script using Javascript which generates a random number between 0-5+1 (Dice.) My issue is that when I press the button, it does nothing half the time forcing me to spam the button multiple times before a dice roll would appear.

I've looked everywhere, but couldn't find any resources as to what the issue might be.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="spin()">Click here to roll the Dice!</button>
<img src="" id="demo">
<script>
function spin() {
        if (Dice() == 1) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/QRTs9Ax.png";
        }
        else if (Dice() == 2) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/OMz1o8U.png";
        }
        else if (Dice() == 3) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/J4Xx2yO.png";
        }
        else if (Dice() == 4) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/CJb2ojk.png";
        }
        else if (Dice() == 5) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/8W6UL5O.png";
        }
        else if (Dice() == 6) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/NGxBete.png";
        }
}

</script>
<script>
function Dice() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value of `dice()` once to a variable and check it with the if statements. You are regenerating the the value each time so there is no guarantee you will get the current value when checking.

<s>Also, as mentioned by paolo, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;` could return `7`.</s>

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="spin()">Click here to roll the Dice!</button>
<img src="" id="demo">
<script>
function spin() {
    var dice = Dice();
        if (dice == 1) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/QRTs9Ax.png";
        }
        else if (dice == 2) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/OMz1o8U.png";
        }
        else if (dice == 3) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/J4Xx2yO.png";
        }
        else if (dice == 4) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/CJb2ojk.png";
        }
        else if (dice == 5) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/8W6UL5O.png";
        }
        else if (dice == 6) {
            document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/NGxBete.png";
        }
}

</script>
<script>
function Dice() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Because `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;` could return `7`.</s>

**EDIT**

`Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;` can't return `7` according to [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) because `Math.random()` doesn't include `1` and [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) just cut the value so you'll always recive a value between `1` and `6`.

The proble is that with `if (Dice() == x)` you start the function so it will retur a diferent vaule for all the is statement. You have to build a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) like this:

```
function spin() {
  switch (Dice()) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/QRTs9Ax.png";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/OMz1o8U.png";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/J4Xx2yO.png";
      break;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/CJb2ojk.png";
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/8W6UL5O.png";
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "http://i.imgur.com/NGxBete.png";
      break;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this can return 7. I am positive it can return values between 1 to 6, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4960020/1333836

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to keep your random number from returning `0` by incrementing it by `+ 1` after flooring. However, when `Math.random()` returns exactly `1.0`, your multiplication will result in exactly `6`, which gets floored to `6` and then gets `+ 1` added to it, making it `7`.

Instead, only multiple your random number by `5`.

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
```

Or, even more simply, just use `Math.ceil()`. Which will always round up to the nearest whole number.

```
return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
```

Comment: I don't think this can return 7. I am positive it can return values between 1 to 6, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4960020/1333836 `Math.random()` doesn't include 1.

Comment: @KaloyanKosev if that's the case, why isn't the function working all the time? Clearly, either a high bound or low bound value is getting generated.

Comment: My guess it that the function is invoked on every if statement. So a total of 6 times. During each of this calls, it returns different value. It might simply not fulfill the condition on any given step.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `Dice()` function on every else if statement.

I've created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/o96kvk3u/) where you can see on the console, which number is been generated, but your spin function would go like this:

```
function spin() {
  var number = Dice();
  console.log(number);
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/QRTs9Ax.png";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/OMz1o8U.png";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/J4Xx2yO.png";
      break;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/CJb2ojk.png";
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/8W6UL5O.png";
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("demo").src="http://i.imgur.com/NGxBete.png";
      break;
  }
}
```

Also you may get the same number multiple times, since it's random.

Answer (score 0):

Just because `Dice()` hasn't static value and may return different value with each if statement, also may return the same random number with multiple if.

So store generated number in a variable and do your if statements as you like.

This below example based on selecting random image from `imgs` array and should do the task as your code do.

```
//add images what ever.
var imgs = [
            "http://i.imgur.com/QRTs9Ax.png",
            "http://i.imgur.com/OMz1o8U.png",
            "http://i.imgur.com/J4Xx2yO.png",
            "http://i.imgur.com/CJb2ojk.png",
            "http://i.imgur.com/8W6UL5O.png",
            "http://i.imgur.com/NGxBete.png"
            ];
    function spin() {
        var d = Dice(); //store the number in a variable
        //Dice(5); ===> if you want the max random number will be 5
        var i = d-1; //to get the right position in array
        if(imgs[i])document.getElementById("demo").src = imgs[i];
        //Also if you want additional statements use if(d == 1){}else if(d == 2){}
    }

    function Dice(max){
    max = max || imgs.length;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    }
```