# Math.random not returning the right value

Tags: javascript, random

So, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here? It's giving me numbers like 3. (I'm passing the variable a as "7-10")

```
function getDmg(a, y) {
    var s = Math.floor((Math.random() * (a.split('-')[1])) + (a.split('-')[0])); 
    if(y == true) {
        console.log('You dealt ' + s + ' damage.');
    } else {
        console.log('You took ' + s + ' damage.');
    }
    return s; // Giving numbers like 3...?
}
```

Comment: The split function is a string function. You should convert the result of the split to a number with `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` before you attempt math on it.

Comment: Just an alternate approach [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc87xbc8/)

Answer (score 0):

Math.random returns random values between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (**exclusive**). To get a number from 7 to 10, you'll need to specify the max value, subtract the min **and then ADD your min value to the result**:

This adjusted code returns random damages in your range. **Remember: if you do want to possibly get a max of 10, you need to pass 11 as the upper value for `Math.random` because the upper value is exclusive**:

```js
function getDmg(a, y) {
    var min = parseInt(a.split('-')[0],10);
    var max = parseInt(a.split('-')[1],10);
  
    var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
    if(y == true) {
        console.log('You dealt ' + s + ' damage.');
    } else {
        console.log('You took ' + s + ' damage.');
    }
    return s; // Giving numbers like 3...?
}

getDmg("7-11", true);
getDmg("7-11", false);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random for more details on `Math.random()`

Comment: I was passing 7-10, hoping for a number in between 7 and 10. But it was giving me numbers waaayy off than what I expected.

Comment: `parseInt` extracts the number at the beginning of a string. It's not exactly string to number coercion. I suggest against using it.

Comment: @Oriol True, but if the input can be regulated (for example `input type=number` or `input type=range`, then it's a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDmg(range, dealt) {
    var damageRange = range.split("-");

    //This will have to be made more "error-proof"
    var min = Number(damageRange[0]);
    var max = Number(damageRange[1]);

    //This formula will take the min and max into account
    var calculatedDamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    console.log((dealt ? "You dealt " : "You took ") + calculatedDamage + " damage.");
    return calculatedDamage;

}
```

Good replies can be found @ [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)