# Generate random daily temperature fluctuation

Tags: javascript, temperature

I need to generate a random temperature fluctuation from 00:00 a.m. to 11.59 p.m. given a central temperature.
Does anyone know a formula to generate a reasonable fluctuation?
I mean, let's say that in summer in Rome average temperature is 30°C; it is reasonable that at 1.00 a.m. is way cooler than 1 p.m.

I don't have any clue from where to start; any suggestion will be welcome.
Thanks.

My language code is Javascript but my question is about a formula

Comment: Probably you want something like [*Generate random number between two numbers*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript?s=1|3.8751) or [*Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range).

Comment: @RobG Kind of, but I also want that the random number depends on Time so that my fluctuation is a curve that may be reasonable real and not a lot of spots which make no sense

Comment: If you expect the generated temperature at 1 am to be cooler than 1 pm, I wouldn't call it entirely random fluctuations. It would be more like sensible temperature ranges and randomly picking values from that range. Also, what do you mean by a central temperature? What are the variables to your functions? As in what inputs would the function expect. For instance it could expect a location and time of day and return a temperature?

Comment: @VivekPradhan Indeed is not 100% random

Comment: @FabioManniti—so what you want is something like a sine curve with small variations either side? Seems to me this is about the formula, not implementation so off topic here.

Comment: Perhaps, if still relevant you can have a look at this: https://leandro.ordonez.tech/ideas/mocking-sensor-data-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
// Time of day 24 hour
var time = 12;
// Base temperature for the day
var tempBase = 10;
// Fluctuations, multiplied with base temperature, indices correspond to hour of the day
var fluc = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

// Work out the temperature of the given day for the given hour 24 format
temp = tempBase * fluc[time]
```

Of course the base temperatures need to be collected/calculated and also the average fluctuations for that day/timespan.

Fluctuations could be given for per day, per month, per week basis or any basis dependent on the accuracy required.

For example, to handle seasonal change one could do;

```
// Fluctuations for each season
summerFluc = [...];
winterFluc = [...];
autumnFluc = [...];
springFluc = [...];

// Fluctuations for months/days etc
fluc = []

// The formula pseudo code would be something like
temp = tempBase * fluc[time] * getSeasonFluc()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end, what I did, was something like a parabola with the formula:
-ax^2+bx+c
In fact I can say that at midnight I have quite much the same temperature that I have at 23.00 and at 12 pm I have the peak of my temperature.
The only think, I chose an interval of fluctuations so that the curve isn't really smooth but may vary and look more real