# Chartjs random colors for each part of pie chart with data dynamically from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I want to set dynamically a color for each part of Pie Chart. Since the chart is dynamically created from database I want for each part that is added to the chart(from database) a different color.

I was trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost/chartjs/projects_chart.php",
method: "GET",
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var ict_unit = [];
    var efficiency = [];
    var dynamicColors = function() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    };

    for (var i in data) {
        ict_unit.push("ICT Unit " + data[i].ict_unit);
        efficiency.push(data[i].efficiency);
         var coloR=dynamicColors();
    }
    var chartData = {

        labels: ict_unit,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Efficiency ',
            //strokeColor:backGround,

            backgroundColor: [coloR],

            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: efficiency
        }]
    };

    var ctx = $("#my-canvas");
    var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: chartData
    })
},
error: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
   },
  });
 });
```

But I only get one color for the first part of the pie chart.

Could you help me?

Comment: instead of dynamic color i want highest marks should be display in red color please any one suggest me

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should create a separate array for colors *( just like the `ict_unit` and `efficiency` )*, instead of assigning a random color value each time to the `coloR` variable.

Here is the revised version of your code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/a7176bce-84e0-11e7-8b99-016f34757045",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         var ict_unit = [];
         var efficiency = [];
         var coloR = [];

         var dynamicColors = function() {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
         };

         for (var i in data) {
            ict_unit.push("ICT Unit " + data[i].ict_unit);
            efficiency.push(data[i].efficiency);
            coloR.push(dynamicColors());
         }
         var chartData = {

            labels: ict_unit,
            datasets: [{
               label: 'Efficiency ',
               //strokeColor:backGround,

               backgroundColor: coloR,

               borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
               //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
               hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
               data: efficiency
            }]
         };

         var ctx = $("#my-canvas");
         var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: chartData
         })
      },
      error: function(data) {

         console.log(data);
      },
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I know it is old, but it would be better if you choose de colors in a deterministic case, saving you from the odd case where you get a repeated color and allowing you to choose a range matching your palette.

Comment: I did it by passing two parameters to your function,  i and data.length.   You can pick the color by changing the offset.  [https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/934/ ]

Comment: instead of dynamic color i want highest marks should be display in red color please any one suggest me

Comment: In @juanlugm code I had to use `Math.round` for the `r, g, b` values. :)

Answer (score 3):

An example snippet for rgb color picker between 235 and 52

```js
const randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (235 - 52 + 1) + 52);

const randomRGB = () => `rgb(${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()})`;

console.log(randomRGB());
```

Resource:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772013/5994546
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228322/5994546
- [https://www.google.com/search?q=color+picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=color%20picker)

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration can be have a Set and avoid color repetition, like this:

```
let data = []; // Some data
let data_labels = []; // Some data labels
let randomBackgroundColor = [];
let usedColors = new Set();

let dynamicColors = function() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

    if (!usedColors.has(color)) {
        usedColors.add(color);
        return color;
    } else {
        return dynamicColors();
    }
};

for (let i in data) {
    randomBackgroundColor.push(dynamicColors());
}

let pie_config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: randomBackgroundColor,
            label: 'Label'
        }],
        labels: data_labels
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
};
```