# Array Of Random Alternate Positive And Negative Number in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, random

I would like to generate array of 10 elements with random number between (-10,10).

And scenario is array can contain positive number between (0,10) for odd positions
and contain negative number between(-10,0) for even position

**For Example**: 1,-2,3,-4,7,-1,3,-3,2,-9

And im totally stucked in generating -ve number at even places because im new in programming.

Any Help Is Appreciated,Thanx In Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: You can generate two sequences with random numbers by using Random.next() and then interweaving them with for example the `.Zip()` LINQ method.

Comment: Thnx for your help but im new in programming so it will become difficult for me i want simple and direct answer

Comment: Throw some code you've tried up there so people can understand where you are in the solution.

Comment: actually i was not stucked anywhere but im thinking the logic for the same as a absolute beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i got your point. *Try This Code*

```
Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0) 
                arr[i] = rand.Next(1,10);

            else 
                arr[i] = (rand.Next(1,10)) * -1;                   
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
```

**Sample Output**
1
-9
9
-8
1
-4
2
-6
4
-9

Comment: `i % 2 == 0` for odd numbers?

Comment: Odd is for real world scenario not in programming actually

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random ();

            var array = new int[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                bool isOdd = (i % 2) == 1; // check remainder

                int randomNumber = random.Next (0, 11); // 0..10

                if (isOdd) randomNumber = -randomNumber; // change sign

                array[i] = randomNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than all the posted answers so far. Here is a basic infinite loop from which to base your specific needs.

```
    public IEnumerable<int> RandomAlternatingSequence()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        int sign = -1;

        while (true)
        {
            sign *= -1;

            yield return sign * random.Next();
        }
    }
```

I realize that the post is 2 years old but this may help others who come looking.