# JavaScript Math Object: Negative , Zero and Positive Value

Tags: javascript

I want to random a numbers like this from -5....0....5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 7-1);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case it returns only -1. It is possible to do in javascript math object?

Comment: [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: Just to add another method `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) - Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a factor of `11` (this returns a value of 0 ... 10) and adjust the number by `-5`.

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) - 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this may this works (There you can give a range also to the random number)...

```
<button onclick="getRandomInt(-5,5)">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
</script>
```

[REF Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: this is useful method. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> In this case it returns only -1. It is possible to do in javascript
>   math object?

You need to use brackets `()`, in your case it resulted in `Math.floor(Math.random() * 7-1 )` => `Math.floor(0.xxx-1 )` => `Math.floor(-0.xxx )` => `-1`

Make it

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (7-1) );
```

> I want to random a numbers like this from -5....0....5.

First get a number between 0 and 5

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (5-0) );
```

Then multiply the same by either *1* or *-1* randomly

```
var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5-0) );
var sign = window.performance.now() % 2 == 1 ? 1 : -1; //get the current timestamp of the system in nanoseconds (something like 1512635632715) and checking if that number is even or odd
value *= sign ;
```

**Added Demo with nano seconds instead of milliseconds**

```js
function generateRandom() {
  var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 0));
  var sign = window.performance.now() % 2 == 1 ? 1 : -1; 
  value *= sign;
  return value;
}

var arr = [];
for( var counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
   arr.push(generateRandom());
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: can you explain this? :  var sign = new Date().getTime() % 2 == 1 ? 1 : -1;

Comment: It's not random. If called 1000 times in one second, it will return number of same sign for all 1000 times.

Comment: @11thdimension how? you meant 1000 times in one millisecond?

Comment: @YadYoung added the explanation.

Comment: Yes, I meant millisecond.

Comment: @11thdimension So how is that a problem? Do you really envisage a random number generator being called so many times within a millisecond? Also only sign value is millisecond based, not the entire value. **Randomness still exists even without sign even though sign generation is reasonably random enough**.

Comment: It's an incorrect answer as simple as that. I can imagine a situation where it will be called multiple times in a millisecond. In fact it will be true for any call in a normal iteration. A biased randomness is not randomness.

Comment: @11thdimension *It's an incorrect answer as simple as that* I don't see how! *I can imagine a situation where it will be called multiple times in a millisecond* Doesn't matter - randomness still exists.