# how to include a random number variable inside the src attribute of img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I have an array of image urls that I need to randomly choose from.

```
var imagesArray = [
       "http://img/img_0.jpg"
     , "http://img/img_1.jpg"
     , "http://img/img_2.jpg"
     , "http://img/img_3.jpg"
     , "http://img/img_4.jpg"
     , "http://img/img_5.jpg"

    ];
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // 0...6
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // 0...6
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // 0...6
```

But instead of the image numbers, I need to include a random number from 0 to 5 in the src of my image tag like this:

```
<img src="http://img/img_[num].jpg" name="canvas" />
```

but [num] doesn't work

HTML

```
<form name="imageForm" class="form1">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://img/img_[num].jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>


    <td>
      <img src="" name="canvas1" />
    </td>


    <td>
      <img src="" name="canvas2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You should use javascript here. Ex : `img.src="http://img/img_"+num+".jpg";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: @Madhavan.V I don't think it is a duplicate of that

Comment: I misunderstood the question, pardon.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL how do I include it in script?

Comment: @jojoli In imagesArray, `"http://img/img_"+ num  +".jpg"`

Comment: Thank you guys for being careful about questions..I appreciate

Comment: @Madhavan.V let me try

Comment: @Swellar how do you think about this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you had an answer..I tried to check it but it disappeared lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbpx1u61/).

```
 <img id="img1" src="" name="canvas" />
```

then script,

```
 var img1=document.getElementById("img1");
    img1.src="http://img/img_"+num+".jpg";
```

Comment: Good luck with @jojo li