# Generate random number in a minute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody know how can I generate random numbers in a specific time period and specific number.

For i.e I want to generate any random number 7 times only in a minute.

I don't know how can I do this using in jquery using setInterval or setTimeout.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks All

Comment: Sounds like a plan! What have you tried?

Comment: divide 1 minute by 7 to get the number of seconds and then run code at that interval, and stop when you get to a minute.

Comment: I have tried generating random number from post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript/7228322#7228322

Comment: are you programming this for the antikythera machine or what? on a normal computer it takes a fraction of a second to generate 7 random numbers.

Comment: Also tried to using setInterval but stuck in how can I generate only 7 times in a minute.

Comment: oh, now i get it

Comment: well I made you a suggestion, did you think of working that out?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I don't want to generate it at the same time.as I said in a minute.

Comment: Pretty sure everyone commenting can surely help you. The issue with your question is that you did not provide what you've tried. Did you get errors? Did it have unexpected results? This isn't a code writing service, and while I'd love the reputation points, I'm not going to do your homework for you. I suggest figuring it out on your own first, and if you run into issues, ask on here and you'll get the help you need.

Comment: @ADyson pretty sure this guy just wants someone to do it for him.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I know that's why I haven't answered. The profile says "Team Lead", so not setting much of an example to the team, really :-(. I think they've got enough clues now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments for an explanation.

```js
/**
 * Generate random numbers at an interval
 * @param perMinute - The number of numbers to generate per minute
 * @param totalNumbers - The total number of numbers to  generate
 * @param minNumber - The minimum number to be generated
 * @param maxNumber - The max number to be generated
 */
function randomNumberAtInterval(perMinute, totalNumbers, minNumber, maxNumber, cb){
    var int = 60000 / perMinute;
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(()=>{
        cb(Math.random() * (maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
        count++;
        if(count >= totalNumbers) clearInterval(interval);
    }, int);
}

// Will generate 7 numbers per minute 
// until it has generated 14 numbers (so for 2 minutes)
// between 0 and 10
// and it will log the number to the console.
randomNumberAtInterval(7, 14, 0, 10, function(randomNumber){
    console.log(randomNumber);
})
```