# Assigning a random value to a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, random

I'm very new to code so I might not understand some answers.
I'm having trouble turning a variable into a random number between 1 and 10 in this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var money = 0

function Random() {
  money = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
</script>
```

I've read that I need to put `return` followed by the randomizing code somewhere but I just don't understand where I place that on how I use it.

Comment: You probably meant to replace `money =` with `return`. Then you can call `money = Random()` to change `money` to a new random integer between 1 and 10.

Comment: Why are you using a function at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Random() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

function getRandom() {
  var money = Random();
  console.log(money);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = money;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getRandom()">Click for random number</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `var money = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);`

Comment: @melpomene Your approach is also right. I duplicate the question and fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked well for the most part but I couldn't work out how to link this to a button. I tried changing a buttons signal to Random but it didn't work. Do you know how I could make a button set off this function so that when i click the button it randomizes the value of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

This line will work:

`var money = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);`

But if you want to use a function, you can write it:

```
var money;

function Random() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

// Re-usable anytime you want
money = Random();
```