# Trouble generating a random number between 0 and 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm working in a discord bot, specifically in a rate command, which is supposed to return:

---

"I would rate (thing to be rated) (random number)/10."

---

But it returns:

---

"I would rate (thing to be rated) [object Undefined]/10."

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + "rate")) {
    if(message.content.slice(prefix.length + 4) === ""){
      message.channel.send("Give me something to rate");
    }
    else
      message.channel.send("I would rate" + "**" + 
        message.content.slice(prefix.length + 4) + "**" + " " + 
        toString(Math.floor(Math.pow(Math.random, 10))) + "/10");
  }
```

What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Also `Math.random()` is a method.  You're missing the `()` to invoke it

Comment: If you want a number between 0 and 10, don't use Math.pow() just multiply 10 on the random number generated. Math.random() * 10. Also wrong use of toString. Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString()

Comment: `toString` is not a function (unless you wrote it) ...`Math.pow` will raise some number to the power another number, (10 in your case), `Math.random` is a function that returns a value between 0 and 1, and any number between 0 and 1 raised to the power of 10 will become a smaller number between 0 and 1, so `Math.floor`, once you fix the `Math.random` thing, will always end up 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to incorporate the following code (considering you want round integers returned):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
```

Ditch the `Math.pow()` method.

*edit made from suggestion by @Geert-Jan*

Comment: If OP wants integers in range `[0, 10]` inclusive the above is not correct, since 0 is never returned. Assuming integer values and an even distribution `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)`  works. Note: Math.random() returns a float in `[0,1)` so the above will never result in `11`

Comment: I'm not following your comment?  Are you making a suggestion to my code?  Sounds like you are just explaining that my code will return integers 0-10 randomly? Help me understand...

Comment: Your code returns integers in range [1,10] randomly. I supplied code to return integers in range [0,10] randomly. Not entirely sure what OP wants though.

Comment: Oh wow - very careless mistake on my part - good catch.  I will make the edit for OP.