# Generate random values and print them in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am creating a google form where I have three sets of values and I want to randomly select one value from all the three sets and print them as a question.

The extension of the script is ".gs"

I tried using RANDBETWEEN(low, high) but the script throws an error. Seems like this is for google sheets.

Requesting for some help on how to create one.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: Include your code as text - not as image.

Answer (score 3):

For you random number, you'll need to use the `Math` library:

```
var nums = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
```

That should give you a random number between 1 and 5.

Comment: How do you set the uppper and the lower limit ?

Comment: Read a proper js reference like at Mozilla's website of W3Schools. Google it and it will give you some deeper understanding, but it's basically like this: <Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + offset> The range starts from 0 (so 0-4 in our example) then the offset shifts to start at a number other than 0, which is 1 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a little bit of confusion here:

- `RANDBETWEEN(low, high)` is a special *Google Spreadsheet* function.
- Inside a Google Script, you must use plain *JavaScript* (plus a few custom Google functions, like the `FormApp.create()` function you're using.)

In JavaScript, `Math.random()` is a way of getting a (pseudo) random number, but it returns a float between 0 and 1. To convert that into an integer in a range we have to use a bit of math. It might be helpful to define your own `getRandomInt` function, [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Then later on you could call `getRandomInt(5)`, returning 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.