# How to randomly duplicate objects on a canvas

Tags: html, random, html5-canvas

I made a fireworks in canvas.
I want to duplicate this to a random location inside the canvas.

Finally, I want to run in random order from random locations.
What more should I add?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

ctx.translate(100, 100);

function fireworks() {
  //clipping
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.clip();

  var x = 130; //final position
  var t = 0; //0-1, this is what you change in animation loop
  var tx = 0; //actual position of element for x

  function myLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2), canvas.width, canvas.height);
    tx = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * x;
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
      ctx.arc(tx, tx, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    if (t < 1) {
      t += 0.01; //determines speed
      requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
    }
  }
  myLoop();
}
EasingFunctions = {
  easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t
  }
}


fireworks();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: You mean, inside the `for` loop?

Comment: yes! is it possible?

Comment: I just ran your code. You mean that the "fireworks" will show in a random place?

Comment: I want several fireworks to appear in random places. but my code has only one fireworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution contains some steps:

1. Call to `fireworks` once the last "firework" done.
2. [Random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960020/863110) the initial firework's position.
3. Clear the `clip` state by `.restore()` and `.save()`

I've added comments in the code.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

function fireworks() {
  // restore and save to reset the "clip" state
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();
  //clipping
  ctx.beginPath();
  // move to a random position in the canvas before drawing
  ctx.translate(random(canvas.width), random(canvas.height));
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.clip();

  let tx = 0; //actual position of element for x
  let t = 0;

  function myLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2), canvas.width, canvas.height);
    tx = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * 130;
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
      ctx.arc(tx, tx, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    if (t < 1) {
      t += 0.01; //determines speed
      requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
    } else {
      // the firework is done, let's create another one
      fireworks();
    }
  }
  myLoop();
}

function random(max, min = 0) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

EasingFunctions = {
  easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t
  }
}

fireworks();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: :) Glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, again.
Your comment was very nice. but I have another problem.
How can I run the next fireworks before the first one is completely over?
I thought about it all day but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Indeed it's more complicated. Do you need specifically this effect? Because there is a library that create great fireworks: https://tswaters.github.io/fireworks/, https://github.com/tswaters/fireworks

Comment: oh... I didn't know that was a complicated task. ok I will study the link you gave me. have a nice a day! :D

Comment: Let me know if you manage to complete your task with that library..