# Generating a random number that is divisible by 10 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, random

I'm making a snake game and have hit a stop when generating the food coordinates.

I want a random number that is divisible by 10. By that I mean that it has to be a number mod(10) == 0. The snake is of width 10 so in order for the coordinates to match, I need numbers like 80, 130, 10, 40, 200

Only even numbers without singulars are allowed. This is my current code:

```js
let width = 100;
let height = 100;
       
let x = Math.floor(Math.random()*width/2)*2;
let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*height/2)*2;

console.log(x + " : " + y);
```

Comment: generate a random integer e.g. between 0 and whatever and multiply it by 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: 21%10 gives you 1. you can add 10-1 to 21 it becomes 30 for example. `Math.random()` gives a random number between (0-1] so you need to multiply that with your range for example 200

Comment: n with n = 0 (mod 10) has the shape n = 10k with k being some integer. So generate a random integer and multiply it by 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `10` in your snippet then (instead of `2`):

```js
let width = 100;
let height = 100;
       
let x = Math.floor(Math.random()*width/10)*10+10;
let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*height/10)*10+10;

console.log(x + " : " + y);
```

- added 10 to avoid 0, I guess that's what you mean on singular. If not, please clarify in the question
- this way code generates `10 <= x <= width` and `10 <= y <= height`, where both x and y are integer multiples of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random multiple of 10 between 10 and 150 by first generating a random number between 1 and 15 and then multiplying it by 10. You can do this in plain JavaScript as follows:

```js
var min = 1;
var max = 15;
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) * 10);
```

Or, you can do it in a cryptographically secure way with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) like this:

```js
console.log(rando(1, 15) * 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```