# How to make a random number generator discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a command that randomly rates you when you do $rate. I just couldn't find a way to make a random number generator. This is my code:

```js
execute(message, args) {
 var rating = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
 message.reply(`I rate you ${rating}/10`);
};
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: "but it doesn't work" That does not explain your problem. What does not work about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake in the code you gave is that it is not `var rating = Math.random() * 10 + 1;`, but `var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;`. It should work if you change it to that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === `?rateme`) {
    var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  message.reply(`I rate you ${rating}/100`);
 }
});
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?