# hello, I would like to have a different random number, but I always get the same, an idea?

Tags: javascript, random

I want to have a random number different when I "click" on my button #roll, but I always get the same number. someone could help me please?

this is my code:

```js
//création nombre aléatoire
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max, min + 1)+ min);
}
numberRandom = getRandomInt(1, 7)

//création du lancé de dé
const roll = document.getElementById("roll")
roll.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  alert(numberRandom)
})
```

```html
          <button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="roll">
          Lancer le dé
          </button>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959975/1707353). It does't explain why yours is broken but I'm guessing you'd rather have the correct code than an explanation.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max, min + 1)+ min);` makes no sense. Did you mean `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)+ min);`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/7924858

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `numberRandom = getRandomInt(1, 7)` is run once when the page is loaded. If you want a different number each button click, just move it inside the event listener

```js
const roll = document.getElementById("roll")
roll.addEventListener('click',()=> {
  numberRandom = getRandomInt(1, 7)  // <=== move it here
  alert(numberRandom)
})
```

Additionally, the calculation doesn't not appear to be correct, I believe it should be closer to

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random number **when you click** then you need to put the code that generates a random number in the function that gets called **when you click**.

Putting it straight in the top level of the script means you generate a random number **once** as the page loads.

Every time the function gets called you read the **same** number from the `roll` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min+1) ) + min;
}

const roll = document.getElementById("roll")
roll.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  var numberRandom = getRandomInt(1, 6)
  console.log('Dice rolled ,you got ',numberRandom);
})
```

```html
<button class="favorite styled" type="button" id="roll">
   Role dice
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer 