# Randomly sort/order item inside a section

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a *section* with few *divs* inside:

```
<section class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```

I prepended an extra item in the *section* with jQuery:

```
<section class="list">
 <div class="extra-item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```

What I want is to randomly sort this extra prepended item within the section – so all the other items are preserving its order but this extra one is sorted on every page refresh:

i.e 1:

```
<section class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="extra-item"></div>
</section>
```

i.e 2:

```
<section class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="extra-item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```

etc...

With the code below I managed to randomly sort all the items inside the *section*; but would it be possible to simply re-order this prepended item and keep the rest in its order?

```
$(function () {
    var parent = $(".list");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your Javascript -- hard to debug what you've written so far without actual code.

Comment: Are you ok with changing your prepend?

Comment: Yes! @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution whichs randomize the action and the position:

```js
// i suppose extra-item is already in the list
const pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(".list .item").length));
const action = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

var item = $(".extra-item").detach();

if(action == 0){
  item.insertBefore(`.item:nth(${pos})`);
}else{
  item.insertAfter(`.item:nth(${pos})`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="list">
 <div class="extra-item">111</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
</section>
```

To avoid memory leak, use detach() instead of remove();

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked like a charm. Is there a known reason why the document 'jumps/scroll' a bit on every refresh?

Comment: its difficult to answer  without seing the problem. and how you refresh the page..when you refresh , you rebuild totally  the html page, following the number of items, you could have scrolling..its just a suggestion..if you dont see , maybe open a new question with the complete code to see what it happens (sorry for my english, hope you understant)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to sort after your `extra-item` has been added, you can insert it into a random location using

```
$(".list>div").eq(__random_position__).before("<div class='extra-item'>")
```

To get the [random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960020/2181514) position, use:

```
var children = $(".list").children();
var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * children.length);
```

however, if you also want it to appear at the start of the list and at the end of the list, then it needs a bit of extra handling:

```js
var children = $(".list").children();
var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * (children.length + 1));
if (position == children.length)
  children.eq(position-1).after('<div class="extra-item"></div>');
else
  children.eq(position).before('<div class="extra-item"></div>');
```

```css
.list > div { height:20px; margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
.item { border: 1px solid green; }
.extra-item { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```