# Random number generator every time the program runs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, random, integer

I am trying to write a code that makes a new random number every time it runs. I have a function here, there is no syntax errors but why does my code not run? And when it does all it does is spit out undefined?

```js
function GetRandomInteger(a, b){

    if (a > b){
        small = b;
        large = a;
    }
    else{
        small = a;
        large = b;
    }

}

var randomInt = GetRandomInteger(1,5);

console.log(randomInt);
```

Comment: you return nothing. You should return something from your function

Comment: Your function does not return anything which is why the output is `undefined`.  Also, if you are trying to make a random number, use `Math.random()`.

Comment: Your code runs but doesn't do anything useful - there is no random generation, you return nothing, also you forgot to declare the variables that you are using (small, large).

Comment: What are small and large? Please add the whole code

Comment: also, the nodejs tag seems to be not useful and not necessary at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, your function does not currently `return` any value, which is why the output of your function is `undefined`.

Also, to make a random number you are better using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) which is a built-in function to accomplish this.  An example would be:

```js
function GetRandomInteger(a, b) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
}

var randomInt = GetRandomInteger(1, 5);

console.log(randomInt );
console.log(GetRandomInteger(1, 5));
console.log(GetRandomInteger(1, 5));
```

This uses `Math.random()` to make a random number between 0 and 1.  It then multiplies this by the *range* between `a` and `b`, and then adds the minimum value `a`.  Finally, it uses `Math.round()` to round the result to a whole number.

In the case of the example snippet above, this returns a number between 1 and 5 (inclusive).

If the case is that `a` can be larger than `b` sometimes, the following modification will permit this to work still:

```js
function GetRandomInteger(a, b) {
  if (a <= b) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
  } else {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (a - b) + b);
  }
}

var randomInt = GetRandomInteger(1, 5);

console.log(randomInt );
console.log(GetRandomInteger(1, 5));
console.log(GetRandomInteger(1, 5));
console.log(GetRandomInteger(5, 1));
console.log(GetRandomInteger(5, 1));
```

Comment: If we want to generate the random numbers in same range, we can generator too. You can include that example too.

Answer (score 0):

this should look like this

```
function GetRandomInteger(a, b){
    let res = {};
    if (a > b){
        res.small = b;
        res.large = a;
    }
    else{
        res.small = a;
        res.large = b;
    }

    return res;
}

var randomInt = GetRandomInteger(1,5);

console.log(randomInt);
```

but this will still not work as "advertised". You want the random number you will not get this like that. You have to use Math.random. Write `math random` in browser there are so many answers and I don't want to replicate them, also I think that probably there is an answer in Stackoverflow already.

Comment: just in case if you want more examples than these that Martin gave, here someone had exactly the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript