# dice roll check if the number is between 1 and 6

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a little dice game but i'm having a problem checking if the number is between 1 and 6.

For an example 1,2,3,4,5,6 all work fine but if i put a zero in front of the number it will still roll the dice but i want it to be only a number from 1 to 6 and i can workout what i'm doing wrong and was hoping maybe someone could tell me.

```js
let diceRolled = false;

const rollDice = (guess) => {
  console.log('guess:', guess);
  
  if (guess == '' || guess === undefined) {
    console.log(`You didn't pick a number from 1 to 6`);
  } else if (diceRolled) {
    console.log(`Dice has already been rolled. Please try again soon.`);
  } else if (!(guess > 0 && guess < 7)) {
    console.log(`You can only pick a number from 1 to 6`);
  } else {
    diceRolled = true;
    let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    console.log(`Dice has been rolled.`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (dice == guess) {
        console.log(`Correct guess - The dice landed on: ${dice} :thumbsup:`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Incorrect guess - The dice landed on: ${dice} :thumbsdown:`);
      }
      diceRolled = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
};

rollDice('03');
```

Comment: Why are you passing `"03"` instead of `3`?

Comment: Duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. Which input fails?

Comment: Because that's my problem if someone puts 03 it will still roll the dice but i don't want it to roll the dice . If the number has a zero in front i want to log `You can only pick a number from 1 to 6`

Comment: @Sebastian Simon there are no input fields the guess is a message from my socket io chat

Comment: @yellowleg Ah. `Array.from("123456").includes(guess)`, then.

Comment: @crashmstr Read the code: `if (!(guess > 0 && guess < 7))`

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Thank you that's what i needed

Comment: Are you aware of the differences of `==` and `===` and how similar to `==`, `<` and `>` will coerce the values and `'03' > 1` as `03` is coerced into `3`? This is why your numeric check fails: any number of leading zeros is ignored.

Comment: @Robby It isn’t. That’s the point. `"03"` is supposed to be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

The below should answer your question. Specifically, I've replaced the `!(guess > 0 && guess < 7)` condition with `!Array.from('123456').includes(guess)`.

```js
let diceRolled = false;

const rollDice = (guess) => {
  console.log('guess:', guess);
  
  if (guess == '' || guess === undefined) {
    console.log(`You didn't pick a number from 1 to 6`);
  } else if (diceRolled) {
    console.log(`Dice has already been rolled. Please try again soon.`);
  } else if (!Array.from('123456').includes(guess)) {
    console.log(`You can only pick a number from 1 to 6`);
  } else {
    diceRolled = true;
    let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    console.log(`Dice has been rolled.`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (dice == guess) {
        console.log(`Correct guess - The dice landed on: ${dice} :thumbsup:`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Incorrect guess - The dice landed on: ${dice} :thumbsdown:`);
      }
      diceRolled = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
};

rollDice('3');
```

However, I'm curious to why `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, `05`, `06` aren't accepted?