# Looping through a JSON array to get a Random value (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through my JSON array and get a random value from it.

Here is my Json Code:

```
{"cities":[{"city":"St.John","xCoor":931,"yCoor":349},{"city":"Halifax","xCoor":844,"yCoor":424},{"city":"Charlottetown","xCoor":838,"yCoor":407},{"city":"Fredericton","xCoor":800,"yCoor":422},{"city":"Quebec","xCoor":734,"yCoor":427},{"city":"Ottawa","xCoor":685,"yCoor":459},{"city":"Toronto","xCoor":655,"yCoor":483},{"city":"Winnipeg","xCoor":420,"yCoor":430},{"city":"Regina","xCoor":336,"yCoor":417},{"city":"Edmonton","xCoor":250,"yCoor":364},{"city":"Victoria","xCoor":111,"yCoor":398},{"city":"Whitehorse","xCoor":115,"yCoor":235},{"city":"Yellowknife","xCoor":285,"yCoor":271},{"city":"Iqaluit","xCoor":645,"yCoor":243}]}
```

In this case I want to loop through the **"Cities"** array and get a random **"city"**.

This is my code to get the Json Data:

```
function getJsonData() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
        schedule = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "capitals.json", true);
xhttp.send();}
```

This is what I have written to try and get the a Random **City** from the **Cities** array:

```
function drawPlanes() {
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cityNames = schedule["cities"];

for(var i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++) {
    var obj = cityNames[i];
    var randomCity = obj.city[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.city)];
    console.log(randomCity);
}}
```

In summary, I essentially just want to loop through this Json Array and get a Random City Value, for example: in the console it just prints lets say "Quebec", but the problem here is that what I wrote is not working. Hopefully what I am asking is clear enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON array" or "Json Code". The content of `schedule` is an object with one property (`cities`) that stores an array of objects.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] and _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Ohhhh, that clears up alot thanks @Andreas

Comment: You should get a random value from 0 to the length of your cities and use that as an index of cities. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `[index]` a random city with `Math.random()`, using `cities.length` as your max value.

```js
const data = {"cities":[{"city":"St.John","xCoor":931,"yCoor":349},{"city":"Halifax","xCoor":844,"yCoor":424},{"city":"Charlottetown","xCoor":838,"yCoor":407},{"city":"Fredericton","xCoor":800,"yCoor":422},{"city":"Quebec","xCoor":734,"yCoor":427},{"city":"Ottawa","xCoor":685,"yCoor":459},{"city":"Toronto","xCoor":655,"yCoor":483},{"city":"Winnipeg","xCoor":420,"yCoor":430},{"city":"Regina","xCoor":336,"yCoor":417},{"city":"Edmonton","xCoor":250,"yCoor":364},{"city":"Victoria","xCoor":111,"yCoor":398},{"city":"Whitehorse","xCoor":115,"yCoor":235},{"city":"Yellowknife","xCoor":285,"yCoor":271},{"city":"Iqaluit","xCoor":645,"yCoor":243}]};

const randomCity = data.cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.cities.length)];

console.log(randomCity);
```

### Edit

If you only want to get the city name, you can get the city property with `.city`.

Comment: my question really here: is there a way for me to get just a random city from cities array? Like just the city and the city only

Comment: @Sslur do you only want the city name? Then do `data.cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.cities.length)].city`

Comment: Thanks that answered my question, @axtck