# RxJS: Handle cancelled events when using `switchMap` operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs, switchmap

Consider the following snippet

```js
const { NEVER, timer } = rxjs;
const { catchError, switchMap, timeout } = rxjs.operators;

timer(0, 3000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => 
    timer(randomIntFromInterval(1, 4) * 1000).pipe(  // <-- mock HTTP call
      catchError(() => {
        // do something on error
        console.log('Caught error');
        return NEVER;
      })
    )
  ),
).subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log('Next triggred')
});

// credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228322/6513921
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  console.log(`Simulated HTTP call ${value}s`);
  return value;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Here the `catchError` would only be triggered when the HTTP call emits an error. But if the HTTP call doesn't return anything within the 3 seconds poll timer, the previous request would be *cancelled* before the next call. I'd like to perform error-handling (essentially triggering the `catchError` operator) over these cancelled requests.

I'm aware we could pipe in a `timeout` with < 3s threshold to throw an error. But I'd like to handle it without using `timeout` operator.

Could anyone come up with a better solution? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest slightly different approach: instead of throwing an error you can just track such cases and apply the logic you need

Here's an operator to do this:

```js
function switchMapWithOvertakeEvent<T, R>(
  project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>,
  onOvertake: (value: T) => void
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  let awaitingResponse = false;
  return (src$) =>
    src$.pipe(
      tap((v) => {
        if (awaitingResponse) {
          onOvertake(v);
        }
        awaitingResponse = true;
      }),
      switchMap(project),
      tap(() => (awaitingResponse = false))
    );
}
```

It can be used with your example as follows

```js
timer(0, 3000)
  .pipe(
    switchMapWithOvertakeEvent(
      () =>
        timer(randomIntFromInterval(1, 10) * 1000).pipe(
          // <-- mock HTTP call
          catchError(() => {
            // do something on error
            console.log('Caught error');
            return NEVER;
          })
        ),
      () => console.log('http call cancelled')
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (value) => console.log('Next triggred'),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
  });

// credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228322/6513921
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  console.log(`Simulated HTTP call ${value}s`);
  return value;
}
```

You can play with the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/mjemgq?devtoolsheight=50

Comment: I'm accepting this solution since it provides different callbacks for errors and cancels. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach would be to use a combination of `race` and `share`:

```js
const src$ = timer(0, 3000).pipe(
  share(),
);

src$.pipe(
  // Making sure the subscriber created from `race` receives
  // the notification first, so that the error can be properly thrown.
  delay(0),

  switchMap(() => race(
      timer(randomIntFromInterval(1, 4) * 1000),
      src$.pipe(switchMapTo(throwError('Request took longer than 3 seconds!'))),
    ),
  ),
  catchError(() => {
    // do something on error
    console.log('Caught error');
    return NEVER;
  })
).subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log('Next triggred')
});
```

Here is my train of thoughts:

By using `share`, I'm essentially telling RxJS to place a `Subject` instance(we will refer to it as `S` as of now) between `timer` and subsequent subscribers. This means that all the subscribers that would initially go to `timer`, will instead go to `Subject`. This is to ensure that there can be as many subscribers as possible, without recreating a new timer every time. Now, let's see why we had to consider multiple subscribers.

When the timer emits `0`, for the first time, `S` will have a subscriber. Then, `race` comes into play:

```js
race(
  timer(randomIntFromInterval(1, 4) * 1000),
  src$.pipe(switchMapTo(throwError('Request took longer than 3 seconds!'))),
),
```

These are the racers: the actual request and the **next notification of the timer**. Let's see the possible cases:

- the request completes before 3 seconds pass; in this case, `race` will do its job and will unsubscribe from the *loser*, in this case the observable which would throw the custom error
- the request **does not complete** before 3 seconds pass; in this case, the winner is `src$.pipe(...)`, meaning that we will get an error which will be caught by the `catchError` operator from the **main pipe**; here is also important to highlight the usage of `delay(0)` - to ensure that the error is first thrown, and then the `switchMap`'s inner observable is unsubscribed; in this situation, there are 2 subscribers that `S` will get - one is from the **main pipe** and the other as a result for using `race`, so by using `delay(0)`, the first subscriber which receives the `timer`'s notification is the `race`'s subscriber

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is an interesting use case for `race` operator.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-87avpe

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  console.log(`Simulated HTTP call ${value}s`);
  return value;
}

const api$ = defer(() => timer(randomIntFromInterval(1, 10) * 1000));
const timerTrigger$ = timer(3000);
api$.pipe(
    takeUntil(timerTrigger$),
    throwIfEmpty(),
    catchError(() => {
      // do something on error
      console.log('Caught error');
      return EMPTY;
    }),
    repeat() // just repeat api
).subscribe({
    next: (value) => console.log('Next triggred'),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
});
```