# How can I change data-id value in Class with a script?

Tags: javascript, html, class

I need to set random **data-id** with two value **A** y **B**. I need a script that can do this

```
<div class="demo" data-id="A" />
....
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you visualize it by adding example html?

Comment: Hmm, it is hard to tell what's going wrong, so read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok thanks, now I've simplified the code. Please, I need a script to change random data-id with value A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For archiving this think you have to do three steps.

First: Collect all values you need into an array.

```
var myPossibleValues = ["A","B"];
```

Second: Generating a random integer number.

Based on [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

```
var randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * myPossibleValues.length);
```

The parameter `myPossibleValues.length` allows you to exentd the array with additional elements and use it as maximum range value.

Third: Read the generated number, apply it on array and associate it to your data attribute.

```
 var videoDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
     videoDiv[0].setAttribute("data-id",myPossibleValues[randNum]);
```

Due to the fact that `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, the `[0]` is nessecary for the -only- first matched html element.

Comment: @RSDNetwork Then please don't forget to mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263609/1579290) is a good solution but since the Issue only needs to select a value from two possibilities I would not overcomplicate things.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
demo.setAttribute('data-id', Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'A' : 'B');
```

What this script does:

- get one element that matches the selector `.demo`
- set the attribute `data-id` to either A or B depending on if the random value is above 0.5 or below - the chances are 50/50