# I want to add random numbers to my renaming script

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

Im very new to JS and node.
I want to edit a bunch of files at once. This works great. But how can I change one of the lines to a random number...

My code looks like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const inputFolder = args[0];
const dir = `${__dirname}/${inputFolder}/`;
const inputFiles = fs.readdirSync(dir).sort();



inputFiles.forEach((file) => {
let id = file.split(".").shift();
let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${dir}/${file}`));

data.name = `Crypto Jackpot Golden Ticket #${id}`;
data.image = `ipfs://QmcDuio2fvEtRmukuTc6yZuh3cyfezX9DqujgduUuSfYLJ/${id}.png`;
data.description = `Hold this NFT to be included in weekly jackpots with 3 entries`;


fs.writeFileSync(`${dir}/${file}`, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
console.log(data);
});
```

Under data.descrition I want to edit a field called "DNA" so I would put:
data.DNA = `//BUT WHAT GOES HERE TO MAKE THIS A RANDOM NUMBER`

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only number or more something like a "UUID" ?

Number:

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
// Min is inclusive and max is exclusive
```

UUID:

```
const { randomUUID } = require('crypto');
console.log(randomUUID());
// '1631f0ef-3bf5-442f-b7e2-6078bf54b192'
```