# How to generate random number?

Tags: javascript

I tried to generate a random number with the click of a button with vanilla Javascript. but my approach does not work.

```js
function webservice_key_key() {
  var input = document.getElementById("webservice_key_key");
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="webservice_key_key" name="webservice_key[key]" required="required" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn ml-1">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary js-generator-btn" type="button" data-target-input-id="webservice_key_key" data-generated-value-length="32">Generate</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? You didn't tell us! And what do you mean by *"mandatory number"* ?

Comment: The goal is to generate an API key. mandatory = random (sorry wrong word)

Comment: how you want to do that ? What are the steps to generate that key and when (on a button click maybe) ?

Comment: You need to display `text` somewhere. The return value of the event listener isn't used for anything.

Comment: You also never initialized `text`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to initialize `text` to an empty string before the loop.
2. You should assign the resulting `text` to the value of the input.
3. The event listener should be run when you click on the `Generate` button, not on keyup.
4. You need to call the `webservice_key_key()` function to add the event listener.

```js
function webservice_key_key() {
  var input = document.getElementById("webservice_key_key");
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let text = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    input.value = text;
  });
}

webservice_key_key();
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="webservice_key_key" name="webservice_key[key]" required="required" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn ml-1">
    <button id="generate" class="btn btn-secondary js-generator-btn" type="button" data-target-input-id="webservice_key_key" data-generated-value-length="32">Generate</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may need to get `data-generated-value-length` and use it in generator

```js
// Run when button clicked
document.getElementById("generate_button").addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Link to input
  const input = document.getElementById("webservice_key_key");
  // Get data-generated-value-length
  const keyLength = this.getAttribute('data-generated-value-length')
  // Generator
  let text = "";
  const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for(var i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  // Set generated value in to the input
  input.value = text;
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="webservice_key_key" name="webservice_key[key]" required="required" class="form-control" size="32">
  <span class="input-group-btn ml-1">
    <button id="generate_button" class="btn btn-secondary js-generator-btn" type="button" data-target-input-id="webservice_key_key" data-generated-value-length="32">Generate</button>
  </span>
</div>
```