# Javascript screen size with condition

Tags: javascript, math, logic, screen

This may sound easy but i am weak in math. I would like to get the value of x that must follow the condition

- The randomised variable x must be larger than radius
- The randomised  variable x must be less than (innerWidth - radius)

  var x = Math.random() * innerWidth ;

  var radius = 20;

Can someone pls help me. I am sure it is more of a mathematics than my coding skills.

[enter image description here][1]

[1]Image Stuck at the screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib1km.png

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript). It details how to generate a random number *inside a specified range*, which seems like what you're trying to do. In your case, `innerWidth - radius` would be the upper bound and `radius` would be the lower bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.random()` gives you a random value between 0 and 1.

So, `Math.random() * n` gives you a random value between 0 and n.

Since you need random values between `radius` and `innerWidth - radius`, we'll get the random values between 0 and `innerWidth - radius * 2` and then add `radius` to it, which will give us random values between `radius` and `innerWidth - radius`. Right?

So, what you need is:

```
var x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - 2 * radius) + radius;
```