# I'm trying to make a TicTacToe Ai to play against. But, I try to make it when the first square is clicked a X appears then a second later a O appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

```js
let O1 = false
let X1 = false
let turn = 0
function Xon1() {
if(O1 === false && X1 === false && turn === 0) {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'X'
    let X1 = true
  setTimeout(compMove, 1000)}}
  function compMove() {
    if(X1 === true) {
    document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O'}}
```

```css
      td {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
</body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td align= 'center'><button id="1" onclick="Xon1()">-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button>-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button>-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align= 'center'><button>-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button>-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button>-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align= 'center'><button">-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button">-</button></td>
        <td align= 'center'><button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

I keep trying different things but whenever I add a if statement to compMove() it doesn't run even X1 does equal true. I can not figure our what is wrong please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run"? Also, how is this problem related to CSS or AI?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you noticed any error when attempting to run your script ? If so, what does those errors tells you. What debugging steps have you taken ? Those are all very important informations because we cannot magically guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question _about code_. It should not ask about a game. Your question, at its core, is about data, not game moves.

Comment: Note your HTML is invalid. There should be no content outside/after the `<body>` element closes.

Comment: You have two versions of X1 - which one do you think is being used in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't declare `X1` again in `Xon1` using let and add IDs to all the boxes
here is the potential code that you are looking for

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      let O1 = false;
      let X1 = false;
      let turn = 0;

      function Xon1() {
        if (O1 === false && X1 === false && turn === 0) {
          document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'X';
          X1 = true; // no need declare X1 again using let so I removed that
          setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
        }
      }

      function compMove() {
        if (X1 === true) {
          document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
        }
      }
    </script>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><button id="1" onclick="Xon1()">-</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button id="2">-</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button id="3">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><button id="4">-</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button id="5">-</button></td> 
      <td align="center"><button id="6">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><button id="7">-</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button id="8">-</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button id="9">-</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

All the best for the next steps.

Comment: still closing the body tag before the table, fyi

Comment: thanks, I just fixed what's broken that's why it was remaining

Comment: sure, just a heads-up

Answer (score 0):

First, you're re-instantiating X1 inside the `if(O1 === false && X1 === false && turn === 0)` statement. That means there are actually TWO `X1` variables. The keyword `let` instantiates a variable with very limited scope, which lives within any block of code (in this case, the `if` statement).

Once a variable is instantiated, you can just update the value with `=`, you don't need `let`, `var`, etc.

Second, you have a few syntax errors in your HTML. In the last row of squares, you have `<button">`. Remove the `"` in each of those.

Third, you don't have `id`s on any other of the buttons other than the first one. Add `id`s to each.

And finally, you're closing the `body` tag before the table. Close the `body` tag right before you close the `html` tag. Scripts should (generally speaking) go into `head` tags, and it looks like that is what you tried.

I edited your post to make it a snippet, btw, which is code that can be run by people who want to help you.

Full example:

```js
let O1 = false;
let X1 = false;
let turn = 0;

function Xon1() {
  if (O1 === false && X1 === false && turn === 0) {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'X'
    X1 = true
    setTimeout(compMove, 1000)
  }
}

function compMove() {
  if (X1 === true) {
    document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O'
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="1" onclick="Xon1()">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="2">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="3">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="4">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="5">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="6">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="7">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="8">-</button></td>
      <td><button id="9">-</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some improvements to your logic would be: Listen to onclick for every button. Call a single function that creates a random number (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript) between 0 and 8 (indexes are 0 based in Javascript). Then, have the AI place a O in that square.

X1 and O1 would be unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Instead of using `onclick`, try adding listeners to the buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: About your suggestion to generate a random number I don't like that idea because it could easily be beaten then but maybe I'll do that if i add a beginner computer.

Comment: Sure, if you can work up a more advanced logic, go for it. My suggestions were just easy next-steps to build from where you are now. Currently, you've hard-coded the computer's first move.

Comment: Why did you accept and vote up the answer that came 5 minutes after mine?

Comment: Yours messed up the bottom three squares

Comment: In what way? They look normal to me.

Comment: Are you referring to the snippet I created in your question? I copy/pasted your own code verbatim.